# How to deploy a ConfigMap using kubernetes client Api

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I want to have the specific configMap structure

```
  apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: config-map-router1
      labels:
        name: nc1
    data:
      object.properties: |
        address: "1"
        port: ""
```

How to represent the indentation with

> object.properties:

We have to develop little more this part of code

```
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("address","");
        //...

        V1ConfigMap configMap= new V1ConfigMap();
        configMap.apiVersion("v1");
        configMap.kind("ConfigMap");
        configMap.metadata(meta);

        configMap.data(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the Java client.
The object.properties indentation appears when you create a configmap from a file. Example: `kubectl create configmap myapp-config --from-file=object.properties`.
[From what I have researched](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1ConfigMap.md) the Java client seems to only support `<string, string>` as values for *data*. As your file object.properties only has UTF-8 characters, you can try:
 `data.put("object.properties","address: \"1\"\nport: \"\"")` 
or creating  a file like the following and opening in Java as a String:

```
address: "1"
port: ""
```

you can also open the file and add to the configmap as a binary, using *binaryData* instead of *data*